# Can I put into variable and echo at the same time?

Tags: linux, bash, variables, ubuntu, echo

I have a script like this:

```
str=$(echo $'Hello World\n===========\n')
echo "$str"
```

And it works!

Can I have something like this?

```
echo str=$(echo $'Hello World\n===========\n')
```

Comment: Your process substitution makes no sense.  The code should simply be `str=$'Hello World\n===========\n'; echo "$str"`

Comment: @tripleee I guess (hope) that the echo is just a simplification of the real program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am able to guess what you want, how about doing a `tee` in the process substitution?

```
str=$(echo $'Hello world!\n====\n' | tee -a /dev/stderr)
```

This has the obvious drawback that the output is redirected to standard error.

<sup>An [earlier version of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26730241/1) critiqued code which was subsequently removed from the question.  See the edit history if you are curious.</sup>

Comment: I'm confused with your answer like we are not reading the same question. There are no while loop in the question, no use of php, no condition. You are redirecting to stderr while in the question the output is done on stdout.

Comment: @Maxime I'm guessing the OP edited the question within the grace period.  I see now how this could be somewhat confusing, but the code was there when I answered.  I agree that redirecting to stderr is a bit of a wart but that's the gist of my proposed workaround.

Comment: If you don't like having the output being redirected to standard error, you can always do some plumbing: `{ str=$(echo $'Hello world!\n====\n' | tee -a /dev/fd/3); } 3>&1`. By the way, the trailing newline is not going to be in variable `str`, but will be shown on output.

Answer (score 3):

In bash there is a variable expansion which might be handy for you :

```
${newvar=value}
```

Try for instance this:

```
$ unset str
$ echo "${str=Hello world}"
Hello world
$ echo "$str"
Hello world
```

And now with your double line example:

```
$ unset str
$ echo "${str=$'Hello World\n===========\n'}"
Hello World
===========

$ echo "$str"
Hello World
===========

$
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that using two instructions is better because people will be able to understand it:

```
str=$(echo $'Hello World\n===========\n'); echo "$str"
```

Comment: You should at least keep the double quotes in `echo "$str"`, otherwise the output will be all on the same line.

Comment: `$()` trims the last newlines, so the command you propose is equivalent to `str=$'Hello World\n==========='; echo "$str"`